# size of correlation matrix using matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, graph, correlation

I am trying to format the matrix better. My current code gives me o/p in the format as seen in the image:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.matshow(final.corr(), fignum = 1)

plt.xticks(range(len(final.columns)), final.columns)
plt.yticks(range(len(final.columns)), final.columns)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And providing a [mcve] would help too